# Observable do not receive the next value in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, angular2-observables

In order to pass value between angular2 different components, I use different services injected into different components.

In my PagesService component, I define a behavior subject and want to pass a value.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../apiService/api.service';
import { Playlists } from '../shared/playlists.model';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class PagesService {

  private currentPlaylists: Subject<Playlists> = new BehaviorSubject<Playlists>(new Playlists());

  constructor(private service: ApiService) {

  }

  getCurrentPlaylists() {
    return this.currentPlaylists.asObservable();
  }

  setCurrentPlaylists(playlists: Playlists) {
    console.log(playlists, 'i am here');
    this.currentPlaylists.next(playlists);
  }
}
```

I need to pass the playlists to a component called PagesComponent

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnChanges, EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { PagesService } from './shared/pages.service';
    import { Subject,BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
  selector: 'pages',
  styleUrls: ['app/pages/pages.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app/pages/pages.html',
  providers: [PagesService]
})
            export class PagesComponent {

              playlists: Playlists;

              constructor(private service: PagesService, private playlistService: PlaylistService) {
                this.playlists = new Playlists();
                this.service.getCurrentPlaylists().subscribe((playlists) => {
                  console.log(playlists, 'new playlists coming');
                  this.playlists = playlists;
                }, error => {
                  console.log(error);
                });
              }
        }
```

This is the console output:
[image]

After I update the playlists, you can see the actual playlists I want to pass printed out to the console, but I do not receive it in pages component,

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it would make a difference, but I've never used the `asObservable()` method before so maybe that's causing some issues? Instead you could do `getCurrentPlaylists(): Observable<Playlists> { return this.currentPlaylists; }`. `Subject` extends `Observable`, so you can just cast it like that. Otherwise your code looks like what I've done numerous times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which component is calling `setCurrentPlaylists()`?

Most likely, some component other than PagesComponent is calling this method and that other component probably has `providers: [PagesService]` defined in its metadata.  This will result in two instances of `PagesService` being created –  one that PagesComponent provides (and injects), and another instance that some other component provides (and injects).